# Remover caracteres não numéricos de uma string

Tags: c#, .net, string, vb.net

Exemplo:

Tenho a seguinte string

> "M1245D454"

e preciso deixar apenas os números nela.

Sobrar M e D são exemplos, quero remover quaisquer caracteres não numérico.

Existe alguma função em C# ou VB.NET para isso?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Se existe algo pronto eu não sei te dizer.

Mas é simples, você pode fazer com uma Regex bem básica

```
string ApenasNumeros(string str)
{
    var apenasDigitos = new Regex(@"[^\d]");   
    return apenasDigitos.Replace(str, "");
}
```

Também tem a opção *regex-free*

```
str = new string(str.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: Em vez de `[^\d]`, pode usar apenas `\D`

Answer (score 4):

É possível fazer sem usar Regex também, usando apenas LinQ (lembrando que todo `String` também é um `IEnumerable(Of Char)`. Em VB.NET eu costumo implementar assim:

```
Dim strFiltrado = String.Concat(
    stringOriginal.Where(
        Function(c) "0123456789".Contains(c) ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu não gosto de RegEx, que apesar de todas as melhorias feitas costuma ser ineficiente e acho feio e ilegível.

Além disso tem resposta que é ineficiente por fazer muitas alocações de memória, além de resolver apenas caso de 2 letras e não do resto, o que tornaria extremamente ineficiente.

Tão pouco gosto do uso de LINQ, ainda que ele não seja trágico, mas é mais legível, menos complicado, e um pouco ineficiente.

Vamos ao jeito manual e eficiente:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text;

WriteLine(RemoveNonDigits("M1245D454"));
                    
static string RemoveNonDigits(string text) {
    StringBuilder newText = new(text.Length);
    foreach (var c in text) if (!char.IsDigit(c)) newText.Append(c);
    return newText.ToString();      
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BTxEl5). E no [**.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i8AJPi). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/RemoveNonDigits.cs).

Imagino que não seja o caso, mas se por acaso precisa eliminar também coisas como ¼ ou ² deve usar o [`IsNumber()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), caso contrário pode ser o [`IsDigit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void Main()
{
string str = "M1245D454"; 
Console.WriteLine("Entrou como: '{0}'", str);
str = str.Replace("M", "").Replace("D", "");
Console.WriteLine("Saiu como: '{0}'", str);
}
//Resultado 
// Entrou como: 'M1245D454'
//Saiu como: '1245454'
```

Segue o [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) do método string.Replace

obs: resposta referente a pergunta original

Mas para a remoção de qualquer caractere não numérico recomendo utilizar `regex` como a resposta feita pelo outro colega. Segue o [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) referente a classe `regex` e seus construtores

Comment: @FelipeWalleg tem o histórico das alterações aqui, se precisar ajustar algo, pode editar novamente. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/123453/revisions