# Imprimir uma string com apenas valores numéricos

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, app, console

Estou fazendo um programa em `console` aonde o usuário digita alguns códigos, e eu quero imprimir esse código de volta pra ele logo quando ele der enter.

Porém eu queria imprimir só os valores números e ignorar os valores não numérico da string.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso? Como eu pego uma variável com o valor de exemplo **a132sb26c33** e imprimo e apenas **1322633** no console?

Comment: Acredito que neste pergunta tenha a resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123453/remover-caracteres-n%C3%A3o-num%C3%A9ricos-de-uma-string. Possível duplicata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue outra alternativa usando `Linq`

```
string dados = "a132sb26c33";
string resultado = new String(dados.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(resultado);
```

Coloquei no [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8Ii2jn) para referencia

Answer (score 0):

Marcelo, aqui já teve um caso similar ([Veja essa resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/291763/78713)).

Nesse caso, o AP pediu que se o caractere tivesse sido digitado repetido, essa repetição seria ignorada também.

Seguindo a mesma lógica dessa resposta, seu casso ficaria assim:

```
var texto = "Abcc111de12234";
var lista = new char[texto.Length];

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < texto.Length; i++) 
    if (char.IsDigit(texto[i])) 
        lista[j++] = texto[i];

var saida = new string(lista);
```

Basicamente, a lógica está lendo a entrada (`texto`) e percorrendo cada caractere dessa entrada, descartando o que não é um dígito (numero).

No final, o resultado é passado para a variável `saida`.

Outra alternativa, usando `Linq` seria assim:

```
var saida2 = new string(texto.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

Esses dois exemplos já adaptados [estão disponíveis para testes no .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u8av8S), explora lá.

Answer (score -1):

```
string input = "There are 4 numbers in this string: 40, 30, and 10.";
// Split on one or more non-digit characters.
string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
foreach (string value in numbers)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
    int i = int.Parse(value);
    Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", i);
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string